# Node.js view not receiving updated data unless route is re-saved

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried searching for this answer but couldn't find anything.

In my node.js index route I am making an http request that captures data and sends it to the view. I noticed that when I visit the page in my browser, the view does not update with the latest data, it only will update if I re-save the index.js file.

> index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');


var url_fx = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22EURUSD%2CUSDJPY%2CUSDCAD%2CUSDCHF%2CGBPUSD%2CAUDUSD%2CNZDUSD%2CUSDMXN%2CEURGBP%2C%20EURJPY%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";

var fx_feed;

//console.log(url_fx)
request(url_fx, function(err, resp, body) {
    body = JSON.parse(body);
    fx_feed="";
    if (!body.query.results) {
      fx_feed = "No results found. Try again.";
    } else {
      fx_feed = body.query.results.rate;
      console.log(fx_feed)
      console.log("updated")
    }
})  

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Title', fx:fx_feed });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Why is this not updating when I hit the page in my browser? Even if I clear cache, it doesn't update.

> Console (after browser request)

```
GET / 304 1256.650 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 7.983 ms - -
GET / 304 87.536 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 3.365 ms - -
```

> Console (after file save in text editor)

```
  { id: 'EURJPY',
    Name: 'EUR/JPY',
    Rate: '138.5375',
    Date: '8/21/2015',
    Time: '3:57pm',
    Ask: '138.5450',
    Bid: '138.5300' } ]
updated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the request into the route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');


var url_fx = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22EURUSD%2CUSDJPY%2CUSDCAD%2CUSDCHF%2CGBPUSD%2CAUDUSD%2CNZDUSD%2CUSDMXN%2CEURGBP%2C%20EURJPY%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";

var fx_feed;

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    request(url_fx, function (err, resp, body) {
        body = JSON.parse(body);
        fx_feed = "";
        if (!body.query.results) {
            fx_feed = "No results found. Try again.";
        } else {
            fx_feed = body.query.results.rate;
            console.log(fx_feed)
            console.log("updated")
        }
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'Title',
            fx: fx_feed
        });
    })

});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I'm executing multiple request functions? I noticed that res.render is within the request function.

Comment: For multiple request in the same route you need to chain them or you can use `async` package. But please edit your question if you need this or open a new one.